# REGEX - Matching again multiple lines

Tags: ruby, regex, rubular

Given text like:

```
XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX. XXXXXXX.

Boss: asdasdasdasd
Date: XXX, XXXXXXXXX
```

I want to match the last 3 lines:

Here's what I'm trying but it's failing:

```
^Boss:.*$^Date:.*$
```

Suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Why does it have to be done with a regex? Just split on newlines.

Comment: +1 @Matt Ball, why does everything look like it needs to be hit with the regex hammer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to skip the first x lines... also you anchor ^ is probably causing you not to match.

Try

```
(?:.*[\r\n]*)*Boss:.*(?:.*[\r\n]*)Date:.*
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^Boss:.*[\r\n]+Date:.*$
```

The line anchors, `^` and `$`, are zero-width assertions; they assert that some condition holds true without consuming any characters.

- `^` means the current position is either the beginning of the input, or it's immediately preceded by a line separator.
- `$` means the current position is either the end of the input, or it's immediately followed by a line separator.

But neither of them *consumes* the line separator, so `$^` can never match.  `[\r\n]+` matches (and consumes) one or more carriage-returns or linefeeds, so it handles the three most common types of line separator: `\r` (older Mac standard), `\r\n` (Windows/network standard), and `\n` (Unix/Linux/Mac OS X/pretty much everything else).

Answer (score 0):

If your file is not of size in GB range

```
ruby -e 'a=File.read("file"); p a.split(/\n/)[-3..-1] '
```