# How do I create a multiline regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to match all text in the block:

```
group :development do
  gem 'test'
end
```

In the context above, I want to return `"gem 'test'"`.
What I'm using is:

```
/(?<=group :development do)(.*)(?=end)/m
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate, see here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239997/regex-how-to-match-multiple-lines

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: [In this way.](http://www.rubular.com/r/jKf0bDZi7T) (no matches are found)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why, but changing the `.*` to `.*?` allows this to match.

Rubular: http://www.rubular.com/r/GaQj6cM0rk

It seems like it should match fine with `.*` as well, but for some reason it doesn't appear to be backtracking.

Here is the Rubular when `.*` is used instead: http://www.rubular.com/r/jKf0bDZi7T

Note that regardless of the reason for this behavior, you should be using `.*?` anyway, otherwise you would only find a single match from the beginning of the first block to the end of the last block (if there were multiple blocks in a string).

Comment: `.*` searches for the longest possible match. `.*?` searches for the shortest possible and is preferable under most circumstances.

Comment: It's because `.*` is a "greedy match", which matches as much as possible, and in this case eats the `end` as well, whereas `.*?` is a non-greedy match and will only eat enough to allow the rest of the regex to match.

Comment: To the above comments, `.*` should also match in this example.  See http://regexr.com?34100.  Even though the `.*` will eat the `end`, the regex engine should backtrack until the match succeeds.

Comment: I've just tried to reproduce this with `/(?<=f).*/` vs. `/(?<=fo).*/` to match `foo` - the latter failed in Rubular, and when I reopened the page in Rubular, the `o` had spontaneously changed into a `0`!! I'm going to investigate further.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Keep me updated!  I am really curious about this behavior.