# Is there a bug in Ruby lookbehind assertions (1.9/2.0)?

Tags: ruby, regex, lookbehind

Why doesn't the regex `(?<=fo).*` match `foo` (whereas `(?<=f).*` does)?

```
"foo" =~ /(?<=f).*/m          => 1
"foo" =~ /(?<=fo).*/m         => nil
```

This only seems to happen with singleline mode turned on (dot matches newline); without it, everything is OK:

```
"foo" =~ /(?<=f).*/           => 1
"foo" =~ /(?<=fo).*/          => 2
```

Tested on Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0.0.

[See it on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/6VryUKUneW)

**EDIT:** Some more observations:

Adding an end-of-line anchor doesn't change anything:

```
"foo" =~ /(?<=fo).*$/m        => nil
```

But together with a lazy quantifier, it "works":

```
"foo" =~ /(?<=fo).*?$/m       => 2
```

**EDIT:** And some more observations:

`.+` works as does its equivalent `{1,}`, *but only in Ruby 1.9* (it seems that that's the only behavioral difference between the two in this scenario):

```
"foo" =~ /(?<=fo).+/m         => 2
"foo" =~ /(?<=fo).{1,}/       => 2
```

In Ruby 2.0:

```
"foo" =~ /(?<=fo).+/m         => nil
"foo" =~ /(?<=fo).{1,}/m      => nil
```

`.{0,}` is busted (in both 1.9 and 2.0):

```
"foo" =~ /(?<=fo).{0,}/m      => nil
```

But `{n,m}` works in both:

```
"foo" =~ /(?<=fo).{0,1}/m     => 2
"foo" =~ /(?<=fo).{0,2}/m     => 2
"foo" =~ /(?<=fo).{0,999}/m   => 2
"foo" =~ /(?<=fo).{1,999}/m   => 2
```

Comment: Well, lookbehind assertions *are*  a new feature since version 1.9, but it's not like this is a very complicated one...makes you wonder what other bugs there are.

Comment: If it's a bug, it's in two different regexp engines (1.9 and 2.0.0 don't use the same engine).

Comment: Well the Ruby 2.0 engine is Onigmo, which is a fork of Ruby 1.9's engine Oniguruma. So if it's really a bug, it may well exist in both engines going unnoticed so far.

Comment: Well, I've opened a ticket in the Ruby bug tracker...: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8023

Comment: In Ruby, 'dot matches all' is _multiline_ mode, and there is no _singleline_ mode as such.

Comment: @MikeM: What Ruby calls "multiline" is called "singleline" in every other regex flavor there is. This is confusing enough :)

Comment: Linked: [How do I create a multiline regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233480/how-do-i-create-a-multiline-regex).

Comment: @dbenhur: Thanks for the additional observations! I've played with them and found a difference between Ruby 2.0 and 1.9's regex engines in the `.+`/`.{1,}` variants of the regex (see above).

Comment: I think it would be helpful and easier to read to many others if you remove the irb/pry prompt from the code chunks, and further put the results on the same line as the code like `"foo" =~ /(?<=f).*/m # => 1`.

Comment: @sawa: Right, thanks, this was getting out of hand :)

Comment: @WayneConrad: It's a slightly different bug in each version. Specifically, `.+` works in 1.9 and fails in 2.0...

Comment: Shouldn't your comment on opening a bug tracker be the answer? And this question be closed? [Or even deleted, since it's almost obvious from the start that this is a bug?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158578/171231) It's a great find, but I don't think it's a great SO question. And especially it isn't an *unanswered* one. (so -1 on the question, but +1 on the comment in an attempt to show this "question" in answered.)

Comment: @ChrisWesseling: I agree, but I'm still waiting for any reaction from the Ruby bugtracker. So far, there has been no activity at all. Until that happens, I'm hesitant to close the question.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling: Also, as is evident from the edits to the question, there have been valuable contributions to the question that helped define the (fairly obvious) bug better; that's something I'm not seeing on the bugtracker either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been officially classified [as a bug and subsequently fixed](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8023), together with another problem concerning `\Z` anchors in multiline strings.