# Issue with a Look-behind Regular expression (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, regex, lookbehind

I wrote this regex to match all `href` and `src` links in an HTML page; (I know I should be using a parser; this just experimenting):

`/((href|src)\=\").*?\"/` # [Without look-behind](http://rubular.com/r/SH7lBidfx2)

It works fine, but when I try to modify the first portion of the expression as a look-behind pattern:

`/(?<=(href|src)\=\").*?\"/` # [With look-behind](http://rubular.com/r/5re3UT1DOj)

It throws an error stating 'invalid look-behind pattern'. Any ideas, whats going wrong with the look-behind?

Comment: This perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234078/is-there-a-bug-in-ruby-lookbehind-assertions-1-9-2-0

Comment: or maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Lookbehind has [restrictions](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kkos/oniguruma/master/doc/RE):

```
   (?<=subexp)        look-behind
   (?<!subexp)        negative look-behind

                      Subexp of look-behind must be fixed character length.
                      But different character length is allowed in top level
                      alternatives only.
                      ex. (?<=a|bc) is OK. (?<=aaa(?:b|cd)) is not allowed.

                      In negative-look-behind, captured group isn't allowed, 
                      but shy group(?:) is allowed.
```

You cannot put alternatives in a non-top level within a (negative) lookbehind.

Put them at the top level. You also don't need to escape some characters that you did.

```
/(?<=href="|src=").*?"/
```

Comment: Oh thanks! Didn't know such a rule! Thanks for the Oniguruma cheat sheet too!

Though, not very relevant to the concept: the above can be solved by having the negative look behind modified like this, hence having the character length same:

`/(?<=(?:ref|src)\=\").*?\"/`