# Match strings with line breaks between two characters

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I match line breaks between two asterisks in Ruby? I have this string

```
Foo **bar**
test **hello
world** 12345
```

and I only want to find

```
**hello
world**
```

I tried it with `\*{1,2}(.*)\n(.*)\*{1,2}` but this matches

```
**bar**
test **
```

I played with a non greedy matcher like `\*{1,2}(.*?)\n(.*?)\*{1,2}` but this doesn't work either, so I hope someone can help.

Comment: Try [`/\*{1,2}\b([^*]*)\R([^*]*)\b\*{1,2}/`](http://rubular.com/r/o3tfM0pWpV).

Comment: thanks this works!

Comment: Do you with to match strings that begin and end with a pair of asterisks and contain a line break? If so, are there any restrictions on the characters between the pairs of asterisks other than the line break? For example, must they be  word characters, or are other characters permitted, including or excluding other line breaks? Can the line break(s) be adjacent to the beginning or ending pairs of asterisks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/\*{1,2}\b([^*]*)\R([^*]*)\b\*{1,2}/
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/o3tfM0pWpV)

**Details**

- `\*{1,2}` - 1 or 2 asterisks
- `\b` - a word boundary, the next char must be a word char
- `([^*]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `*`
- `\R` - a line break sequence
- `([^*]*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than `*`
- `\b` - a word boundary, the preceding char must be a word char
- `\*{1,2}` - 1 or 2 asterisks

Answer (score -1):

Wiktor already gave a good answer. Here is another way of doing it:

```
(?<=\*{1,2})([^*])*(?=\*{1,2})
```

[Tested here](http://regexr.com/3u1kp)

NOTE: This will not work in Ruby, but it can work in some other languages

From the link in [this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947331/issue-with-a-look-behind-regular-expression-ruby)

> Subexp of look-behind must be fixed-width.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the note. I was debating whether I should leave this answer since it doesn't work in Ruby. It might help someone who needs something similar in JavaScript, for example.