# Ruby regular expression to get users names after @ symbol

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I get the username without the @ symbol?
That's everything between @ and any non-word character.

```
message = <<-MESSAGE
From @victor with love,
To @andrea,
and CC goes to @ghost
MESSAGE
```

Using a Ruby regular expression, I tried

```
username_pattern = /@\w+/
```

I will like to get the following output

```
message.scan(username_pattern)
#=> ["victor", "andrea", "ghost"]
```

Comment: CertainPerformance I tried `/@\w+/`

Comment: The [twitter-text](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text) gem can [extract](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/rb#extraction) @-mentions.

Comment: Still waiting for an answer that is deserving of the green checkmark?

Answer (score 3):

Use look behind

```
(?<=@)\w+
```

this will leave @ symbol  [regex](https://regex101.com/r/xBpNip/1)

Comment: At the moment this is the best answer which fulfils the requirements. Can you please explain the `?<=` in the regex? Thank you.

Comment: `?<=` is the look behind operator. It matches from the character next to it and not itself. `\w+` will match the words or digits continuously without any space or anyother special characters

Comment: Best to be precise. `(?<=@)` is a *positive* look-behind expression. It means that the string `"@"` must immediately precede the match that follows, but is not part of the match. `\w+` matches a sequence of one or more *word characters*, namely, letters (uppercase or lowercase), digits or underscores (`"_"`).

Answer (score 1):

I would go with:

```
message.scan(/(?<=@)\w+/)
#=> ["victor","andrea","ghost"]
```

You might want to read about [look-behind regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19947764/2483313).

Comment: It also matches the `,` at the end in `andrea,`

Comment: I believe we don't want to include the `,`.

Comment: @victorhazbun, but you wrote in the question: _everything between @ and space_.

Comment: Thanks @spickermann, I just updated the SO question description. Sorry.

Comment: @victorhazbun: Updated my answer to address your updated question.

Comment: @spickermann thanks for pointing out the "look-behind regexp" link.

Answer (score 1):

You could match the `@` and then capture one or more times a word character in a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)

`@(\w+)`

```
username_pattern = /@(\w+)/
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y7dJnD/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
irb(main):010:0> message.scan(/@(\w+)/m).flatten
=> ["victor", "andrea", "ghost"]
```