# Invalid pattern in look-behind

Tags: python, regex, ruby, regex-lookarounds

Why does this regex work in Python but not in Ruby:

```
/(?<!([0-1\b][0-9]|[2][0-3]))/
```

Would be great to hear an explanation and also how to get around it in Ruby

EDIT w/ the whole line of code:

```
re.sub(r'(?<!([0-1\b][0-9]|[2][0-3])):(?!([0-5][0-9])((?i)(am)|(pm)|(a\.m)|(p\.m)|(a\.m\.)|(p\.m\.))?\b)' , ':\n' , s)
```

Basically, I'm trying to add `'\n'` when there is a colon and it is not a time.

Comment: What do you want to match with `\b`? What is your pattern supposed to match?

Comment: What is this supposed to match or not match on? Give us use cases, too, to test.

Comment: Btw, if a negative look behind assertion matches, it will never be able to capture anything in it's content constructs.

Comment: @tadman added more info

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew updated the post

Comment: @sln Error is "Invalid pattern in look-behind"

Comment: https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyuwadc6r The fix  https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydutj3ar

Comment: So, just change the beginning to `(?<![0-1\b][0-9])(?<![2][0-3])` and it works for all engines.

Comment: The point is that `\b` when used in a character class is no longer a word boundary. In Python, it is a backspace char. In Ruby, the problem seems to be related to the capturing group inside the negative lookbehind. `(?<!([0-1\b][0-9]|[2][0-3]))` must be turned into `(?<![0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])(?<!\b\d)` - if all you want is to match either `[0-1]` or word boundary with `[0-1\b]`

Comment: Does  [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57107659/3832970) work for you in both Ruby and Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby regex engine doesn't allow capturing groups in look behinds. 
If you need grouping, you can use a non-capturing group `(?:)`:

```
[8] pry(main)> /(?<!(:?[0-1\b][0-9]|[2][0-3]))/
SyntaxError: (eval):2: invalid pattern in look-behind: /(?<!(:?[0-1\b][0-9]|[2][0-3]))/
[8] pry(main)> /(?<!(?:[0-1\b][0-9]|[2][0-3]))/
=> /(?<!(?:[0-1\b][0-9]|[2][0-3]))/
```

[Docs:](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kkos/oniguruma/master/doc/RE)

```
 (?<!subexp)        negative look-behind

                     Subexp of look-behind must be fixed-width.
                     But top-level alternatives can be of various lengths.
                     ex. (?<=a|bc) is OK. (?<=aaa(?:b|cd)) is not allowed.

                     In negative look-behind, capturing group isn't allowed,
                     but non-capturing group (?:) is allowed.
```

Learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947331/issue-with-a-look-behind-regular-expression-ruby).

Comment: I saw the capture groups causing error in lookbehinds, but when I change it to non-capture groups it  times out.

Comment: Should `(?<=aaa(?:b|cd))` be `(?<=aaa(b|cd))` that is not allowed ?

Comment: What is the string it  times out on? Maybe there is some excessive bactracking

Comment: It times out on `(?<!(?:[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]))` not a lot to backtrack on with this. link  https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyda5tvar

Comment: What is the string that you're matching with this regex?

Comment: It works fast on my computer:
`[10] pry(main)> /(?<!(?:[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]))/ =~ ':: ;:;'
=> 0`

Comment: I guess from that answer, the non-capture group in this  `(?<=aaa(?:b|cd))` is not the _top level_ but it should be for `(?<=(?:a|bc))` right ? But, if only that's allowed, then you don't need `(?: )` ever at all.

Comment: That's why I don't trust online ruby testers.

Comment: I'm gonna have to rate Ruby as having a bizzaro world regex engine. haha

Answer (score 2):

Acc. to [Onigmo regex documentation](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/blob/master/doc/RE), **capturing groups are not supported in negative lookbehinds**. Although it is common among regex engines, not all of them count it as an error, hence you see the difference in the `re`  and Onigmo regex libraries.

Now, as for your regex, it is not working correctly nor in Ruby nor in Python: the `\b` inside a character class in a [Python](https://ideone.com/Q01Lr3) and [Ruby](https://ideone.com/OkZ3GJ) regex matches a BACKSPACE (`\x08`) char, not a word boundary. Moreover, when you use a word boundary after an optional non-word char, if the char appears in the string a word char must appear immediately to the right of that non-word char. The word boundary must be moved to right after `m` before `\.?`.

Another flaw with the current approach is that lookbehinds are not the best to exclude certain contexts like here. E.g. you can't account for a variable amount of whitespaces between the time digits and `am` / `pm`. It is better to match the contexts you do not want to touch and match and capture those you want to modify. So, we need two main alternatives here, one matching `am`/`pm` in time strings and another matching them in all other contexts.

Your pattern also has too many alternatives that can be merged using character classes and `?` quantifiers.

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/33Sj3s/2)**

- `\b((?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\s*[pa]\.?m\b\.?)`:

  - `\b` - word boundary
  - `((?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\s*[pa]\.?m\b\.?)` - capturing group 1:

    - `(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])` - an optional `0` or `1` and then any digit or `2` and then a digit from `0` to `3`
    - `:[0-5][0-9]` - `:` and then a number from `00` to `59`
    - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
    - `[pa]\.?m\b\.?` - `a` or `p`, an optional dot, `m`, **a word boundary**, an optional dot
- `|` - or
- `\b[ap]\.?m\b\.?` - word boundary, `a` or `p`, an optional dot, `m`, **a word boundary**, an optional dot

[Python fixed solution](https://ideone.com/rq5cDW):

```
import re
text = 'am pm  P.M.  10:56pm 10:43 a.m.'
rx = r'\b((?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\s*[pa]\.?m\b\.?)|\b[ap]\.?m\b\.?'
result = re.sub(rx, lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else "\n", text, flags=re.I)
```

[Ruby solution](https://ideone.com/feVg9X):

```
text = 'am pm  P.M.  10:56pm 10:43 a.m.'
rx = /\b((?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\s*[pa]\.?m\b\.?)|\b[ap]\.?m\b\.?/i
result = text.gsub(rx) { $1 || "\n" }
```

Output:

```
"\n \n  \n  10:56pm 10:43 a.m."
```

Answer (score 0):

For sure @mrzasa found the problem out.

But .. 
Taking a guess at your intent to replace a non-time colon with a ':\n`
it could be done like this I guess. Does a little whitespace trim as well.

```
(?i)(?<!\b[01][0-9])(?<!\b[2][0-3])([^\S\r\n]*:)[^\S\r\n]*(?![0-5][0-9](?:[ap]\.?m\b\.?)?)
```

PCRE - https://regex101.com/r/7TxbAJ/1 Replace `$1\n`

Python - https://regex101.com/r/w0oqdZ/1 Replace `\1\n`

Readable version

```
 (?i)
 (?<!
      \b [01] [0-9] 
 )
 (?<!
      \b [2] [0-3] 
 )
 (                             # (1 start)
      [^\S\r\n]* 
      :
 )                             # (1 end)
 [^\S\r\n]* 
 (?!
      [0-5] [0-9] 
      (?: [ap] \.? m \b \.? )?
 )
```