# SyntaxError: (irb):4: invalid pattern in look-behind (positive look-behind/ahead)

Tags: regex, ruby, regex-lookarounds, gsub, regexp-replace

I am trying to write a regex-replace pattern in order to replace a number in a hash like such:

[regexr link](https://regexr.com/5tfcr)

```py
some_dict = {
  TEST: 123
}
```

such that 123 could be captured and replaced.

`(?<= |\t*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+: |\t+)\d+(?=.*)`

You'll see that this works perfectly fine in regexr:
[image]

When I run this gsub in irb, however, here is what happens:

```sh
irb(main):005:0> "  TEST: 123".gsub(/(?<= |\t*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+: |\t+)\d+(?=.*)/, "321")
SyntaxError: (irb):5: invalid pattern in look-behind: /(?<= |\t*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+: |\t+)\d+(?=.*)/
```

I was looking around for similar issues like [Invalid pattern in look-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57102938/invalid-pattern-in-look-behind) but I made sure to exclude capture groups in my look-behind so I'm really not sure where the problem lies.

Comment: FYI: Use https://rubular.com/ for testing Ruby regexp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that Ruby's Onigmo regex engine does not support infinite-width lookbehind patterns.

In a general case, *positive lookbehinds* that contain quantifiers like `*`, `+` or `{x,}` can often be substituted with a consuming pattern followed with `\K`:

```rb
/(?: |\t*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+: |\t+)\K\d+(?=.*)/
#^^^                         ^^
```

However, you do not even need that complicated pattern. `(?=.*)` is redundant, as it does not require anything, `.*` matches even an empty string. The positive lookbehind pattern will get triggered if there is a space or tab immediately to the left of the current location. The regex is equal to

```
.gsub(/(?<=[ \t])\d+/, "321")
```

where the pattern matches

- `(?<=[ \t])` - a location immediately preceded with a space/tab
- `\d+` - one or more digits.

Comment: if there is any chance of a number appearing after `123` like in a comment for example, do i need to add a lookahead as well?

Comment: @notacorn Positive lookaheads are used to require a specific string context. `.*` matches an empty string, so your positive lookahead is redundant.