# My main syntax checker condition is not passing all my string combinations

Tags: javascript, regex

This should pass the condition:

```
syntax_search = (){return 0;}
syntax_search = ( ) { fsf return 0;}
syntax_search = ( ) { return 0; }
syntax_search = (){ return; }
syntax_search = (){ if(x){ sdfsdf } return 0;}
syntax_search = (){ char x[20]; return };
```

It is not passing all the combinations above, What is the right way?

```
if( /^\s*(\s*)\s*{[\s\S]*\s+return\s*[0-9]*\s*;\s*}\s*/.test(syntax_search) )
```

Comment: you keep resetting syntax_search... are you trying to make an array?

Comment: No, syntax checking. those are just combinations that must pass the condition

Comment: Escape the curly brackets `{}` -->  `\{\}`

Comment: What do you think `\s*(\s*)\s*` matche?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build a language parser. Regular expressions is not your tool of choice for that - consider a parser generator, like [PEG](http://pegjs.majda.cz/) instead.

Comment: @thg435 - I know, but i designed my own, this is only for newbie programmers of c++

Comment: @M42 escaping braces is usually unnecessary if they don't form a valid quantifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You regular expression contains many unneeded complexities and there are some characters that need escaping such as `{` and `}`.

Anyway you can use this modified version of your regex and it should work.

```
^\s*\(\s*\)\s*\{(.*(return\s*\d*\s*;)\s*)\}\s*;?$
//                                  ^
//                                  |
//                             There was a ? here
```

[Regex 101 Demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/zQ0uK9)

Comment: i still need that return ; or return [0-9] ;

Comment: my code-editor project will not support function def, so return must just be encountered for main syntax

Comment: it seems like [^0-9,]+ is not integrated to the post?

Comment: this must pass: return ; or return 0; but not: return x

Comment: You forgot to anchor the expression: 
"whatever I want here" (){ char x[20]; return }; "whatever I want here too"

Comment: @Sylverdrag I actually didn't forget. I though he can handle this bit himself. Anyway for the sake of completeness I will add them right away. Thanks.

Comment: @sniffer: one last thing, return w/out ; is passing the condition, it should not

Comment: @sniffer: #include<iostream.h>

int main(){
return
}

Comment: @fireflieslive Please remove previous comments so we can reduce cluttering a bit, and I have fixed the issue. All you have to do is to remove the optional meta-character `?` after the semicolon, check my modified answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

1. As M42 pointed out, you need to escape the curly brackets
2. The parentheses at the begining also need to be escaped (otherwise you are defining a capture group)
3. "return" is required by the expression. Your first 2 test cases don't contain the word return and will fail. Is that on purpose?
4. Same as #3 for `;`.
5. `[\s\S]*` Anything which is a space and everything which isn't. Replace by a dot `.*` If you need to also match a newline, use `[^]*`
6. This regex is not anchored to the end of the string so it will allow invalid strings. (You can put anything you want after the last }

   /^\s*(\s*)\s*{[^]*return\s*\d*\s*;\s*}\s*$/

Comment: Curly brackets should be escaped, but if it would be invalid (i.e., doesn't have numbers and commas only inside ) it works, e.g. `"{abc}".match(/{abc}/g)`.  `/[\s\S]*/` is the same as `/.*/m`, note the m.  Otherwise it doesn't match newline characters.  Just notes, not criticism.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand No sure what's your first point. For your second, the test cases are all in one line. To match everything including a newline char, "[^]*" is a better choice in javascript. "m" does NOT make "." match newline, it causes $ to match the end of every line individually.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Actually, that one is consistent. Normally the flag you want is "s" for single line, but it is not supported by javascript.

Comment: Ruby's "m" makes `.` also match new lines \[[1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5240101)]\[[2](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html)].

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. Every language I had encountered so far used the "s" flag for that and "m" to do the opposite.