# Regex to match string over multiple lines

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm using a regex to match strings in a source file. I have a regex:

```
(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1
```

It matches the opening and closing quotes only if they are on the same line. For example,

```
"hello world!"
```

matches, but

```
"hello
world!"
```

does not.

Is it possible to modify this so that both cases are matched?

Comment: This may depend on the tool/language you are using.  I believe what you need here is for the regex to be in DOTALL mode, meaning that dot also matches newline.  Update with the tool you are using.

Comment: If the language you're using doesn't have a `DOTALL` or `s` flag, you can use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, I've updated the question.

Comment: As a side note, unless you've got a special case with backslashes you didn't tell us about, it looks like `(["']).*?\1` would work just as well, while being much less confusing.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239997/regex-how-to-match-multiple-lines) would seem to have you covered.  As I'm not a Ruby person, I won't attempt an answer.

Comment: @mudasobwa It matches plenty. Including the shown example.

Comment: @Stefan oh, indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the flag m (`/regexp/m`)

It's getting a little old, but http://rubular.com/ has a ruby regexp testing interface and the basic classes and modifiers remainder.